# Vaadin jetty live reload not picking up class changes

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I've created a fresh Vaadin app from the maven archetype and run it through the maven jetty plugin. In the log I see the "Scan interval sec = 2" but it's not picking up any java changes (IntelliJ). If I do a full "mvn compile" (which takes too long to be practical anyway) I end up with a 503.

Any pointers on where to start looking for the root of the problem?

Comment: Do you press the magic compilation key sequence in IntelliJ so it actually compiles the file? (shift-cmd-f9 or similar)

Comment: That gives a 

```jakarta.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener@2f598d89{src=ANNOTATION:com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener}```


On a side note it's interesting because I thought that Ctrl+S did an implicit compile since Quarkus dev mode picks up changes but apparently it has a more aggressive apporach against the actual source file...

Comment: Hmm, I have 3.8.3 so it could be https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16097, checking

Comment: Yep, upgrading maven fixed the exception